# Why child package can't use the parent package default class or default method?

Tags: java, package

For example

```
package a
    |_ public class AA { a(){} }
    |_ class A {}

package a.b
    |_ 
      class B {
        b() {
          new AA().a(); // error
          new A(); // error
        }
      }
```

I want to know why java design the default.
Why the package a.b is not the package a?

Comment: Because then you would have to make sure that every class name in a hierarchy is unique, instead of just in a single package. Or otherwise if you had the classes `a.A` and `a.b.A` and then in class `a.b.c.B` you would write `new A()` what should it refer to? `a.A` or `a.b.A`?

Comment: `new A().a();` is not possible because class `A` is not having method `a()` and is not extending `AA`.

Comment: Sorry, the true example is next comment. Rename the name A and AA make the example error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, maybe the a.A and a.b.A is the answer for the new A(). But why the new AA().a() is also error?(the true example see my next comment). And if the reason is distinguishing the a.A and the a.b.A. Why don't forbid the a.b.A when there has the a.A? I want to know the designer design idea. Why package make people feel confused?

Comment: Despite looking like that, packages don't actually have a "parent/child relationship" in any meaningful way. The pair `a`/`a.b` has exactly the same relationship as the pairs `a.b`/`a.c` and `a` /`x` do (i.e. none).